# Achieving wireless + speedlight

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

I have a Nikon D5100, and would like to be able to hold a speedlight in my hand, or place it behind my subject. I'd like to avoid cables, but don't know which specific products I should get. I currently have an SB-400, which I'm willing to replace.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few main options you can use for this.  You can use Nikon speedlights that include slave functionality with one flash or control unit that provides master functionality for their wireless optical sync.

Another option that requires purchasing a few more devices, but would allow use of your SB-400 is to buy PocketWizards.  PocketWizards or similar products are third party wireless transmitters and receivers for hotshoe flashes.  They aren't super cheap, but aren't terribly expensive either when compared to remote capable flashes (particularly master flashes).  The advantage is that you can use them with any flash you already have and they can be radio controlled, but the disadvantage is that they are a third party system and thus are not guaranteed to be forward compatible (though the record is pretty good).

Comment: The SB-400 will not work with many wireless receivers.  Looks like they do work with the latest PocketWizards, but I know they will not fire with many other brands, so be sure to check compatibility before buying.

Comment: I'm not too worried about sticking with the SB-400. I'm more concerned that using the D5100 with the on-board flash as a trigger would require line-of-sight. Is that inaccurate? Thanks.